# Copy empty folders from an Azure Data Lake Store using Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am using Data Factory v1 to copy folders from a source Data Lake Store to a destination Data Lake Store for backup purpose.

Unfortunately it does not copy empty folders, this is by design I think if I read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system)

*Note when recursive is set to true and sink is file-based store, empty folder/sub-folder will not be copied/created at sink*

But for my backup this is not an option, is it possible to also copy folders using Data Factory?

Comment: I'm afraid copying empty folders in ADF is not supported yet.

Comment: Could you use a custom .net  data factory activity (or alternative means) to create dummy placeholder files?